# Droid X2 constantly changing USB mode to PC mode

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, motorola-droid-x2

So I'm trying to manually backup my SD card and transfer over files to flash the CM9 alpha4 to my phone, but it apparently decided to just start automatically switching to PC Mode. No matter how many times I try to switch to USB Mass Storage, it changes back to PC Mode before the drives can even mount.

The only thing I've done since I was last able to change modes was upgrade Titanium Backup to the Pro version and run a backup.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB cable?

Comment: I tried 2 factory cables and a non-factory cable.

Anyways, I just transferred the CM9 files with Dropbox and flashed. The issue didn't persist after flashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I transferred the CM9 files with Dropbox and flashed. The issue didn't persist after flashing.